# JBoss seems to hang on startup at the command line

Tags: jboss, startup

I am trying to run JBoss from the command prompt with the standalone.bat file.  It starts the startup process but then just sits there.  I couldn't really find any answers with Goolgle or on here.

Here is the output from my command line:

```
C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>standalone
Calling "C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================

JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\java

JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx51
2M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.se
rver.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.war
ning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.c
onfig=standalone.xml

===============================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; sup
port was removed in 8.0
16:06:41,708 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
16:06:42,009 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
16:06:42,075 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" sta
rting
```

And it just sits right here.  Any ideas of why it doesn't finish starting up?

This is added info...
I took Omoro's suggestion and went back to Java 7.  That got JBoss to not "hang" anymore at the command line.  Now when I run standalone.bat it says

Calling "C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"

and then just goes back to the command prompt without starting JBoss.  I will open a new thread since the old problem has been cured and now a new problem has arisen.

Thanks for everyone's help especially Omoro.

Comment: Have you checked what's logged in server.log?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this server log thing out.  The server log that I see doesn't seem to get updated when I try to start and stop JBoss.  There is a boot.log that gets written to every time I start and restart JBoss.
Also, I'm not sure what I am looking for in the log.

Comment: There should be a log folder inside the standalone where the server.log is written to and in the log you can see lines with exceptions  /errors and their causes and from the causes you can figure out what the possible problem might be. See if you can find that or look also in the boot.log.

Comment: Can you try using Java 7 instead of 8 and see if you get the same problem. Also try checking the standalone.xml (Iam assuming you are using standalone) if it doesn't contain errors if you have edited it or something like that.

Comment: @omoro  -- I do not see any errors in the boot.log.  It tells me JBoss is starting then a whole bunch of stuff before it tells me that JBoss is stopping (I hit ctrl-c to stop it).

Also, the reason I'm trying to start at the command line is because when I tried to start in Eclipse I get an error that a configuration file does not exist... namely standalone.xml.  but that is not mentioned when I try to run from the command line.

Comment: Try starting it by clicking the standalone.bat in the bin folder

Comment: Ok, I will uninstall Java 8 and install Java 7 and see.  I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: I uninstalled Java 8 and installed Java 7.  Now when I run standalone at the command line I get a single line of output as follows:  

C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>standalone
Calling "C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final  \bin\standalone.conf.bat"  

C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin>

Answer (score 34):

This is a known issue. See more discussion at:

https://community.jboss.org/message/808212

Quoting from the thread:

> Yes it is normal.
>
> There have been some changes in JDK8 that prevent 
>   AS7 and current version of EAP6 to start under JDK8.   We have many
>   JDK8 related fixes in WildFly so I would recommend you to use that.
>
> As for EAP goes, the start up on JDK8 is fixed in upcoming 6.2 release.

Comment: Yes, just set something like export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_25/ before start in dev mode, or appropriate config for OS

Comment: This happened to me when was trying to start JBOSS FSW, so internally use JBOSS EAP 6.1

Answer (score 16):

Use WildFly 10, works like a charm even with Java 8.

Remember `JBossAS` changed name to `WildFly`.

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue when starting JBoss 7 with Java version 8. All you need to do is change to Java version 7 or 6 and then try to start JBoss again.
For ubuntu user use following command to change default Java JDK version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This will give you a list output similar to this:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing        
/usr/bin/java).
   Selection    Path                                               Priority   Status
  ------------------------------------------------------------    
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java         1070          auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1051          manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1069          manual mode
Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Select proper option and this will change default Java JDK version.

To verify type:

```
$java -version
```

Answer (score 5):

Solution : This Issue comes when Java jdk1.8.0_40 is installed in your system and the same is mapped in JAVA_HOME system variable . This issue can be sorted out by installing Java 7 with its jdk jdk1.7.0_79 and mapping the same in JAVA_HOME as C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 . The JBOSS server will start successfully .

Answer (score 2):

I too came across this issue. Firstly I downgraded to `JDK 1.7` and it happened to work smoothly but as I wanted to work on `JDK 1.8`, I downloaded `WildFly 10` former `JBossAS`.

It works smoothly without any compatibility issues.

Comment: can you please give any link on how to downgrade to java 7. I have tried some, but still not working

Comment: @BlizZard Wots the IDE you are currently using ?

Comment: @DulithDeCosta i just wanna install java 7 on my system. No IDE used till now, just terminal tring to install by terminal commands

Comment: @BlizZard Go to Command Prompt and type 'java -version' and check the existing java version.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to work with JBoss7.1, downgrade your java version from 1.8 to 1.7 or 1.6. (To check your current java version type java -version in command line). Otherwise, you can change your application server to Wildfly as stated in previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

For those who're facing this issue while starting JBoss 7.1 in Eclipse:

1. Navigate to Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Installed JREs
2. Add/Select JDK/JRE 1.6/1.7
3. Navigate to Window --> Preferences --> Server --> Runtime Environments
4. Select JBoss 7.1 Runtime Environment and click 'Edit'
5. Select JRE 1.6/1.7 as Runtime JRE

Answer (score 0):

Instead of jdk 8 (it has old compatibility problem with jboss), use only version which your project required.