# JBoss 7 with JAVA 8

Tags: java, jboss

I noticed that when I upgraded my JDK from JAVA 7 to 8, my JBoss Server would no longer startup. I reverted back to JAVA 7, and JBoss works fine. Has anyone seen this behavior in your JBoss installations? I'm guessing JBoss isn't compatible with JBoss 7 at the moment?

Comment: What startup failure reasons does it report?

Comment: Known problem. See [JBoss seems to hang on startup at the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22902077/3536342) for more information.