# Arquillian: starts the server but doesn't deploy

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian

I am adding Arquillian to my project, I started with helloworld example:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class AccountTest {
    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class).addClasses(CustomerLookupLocal.class, CustomerLookup.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToReadSysPropAtStartup() {
        Assert.assertTrue(1 == 1);
    }
```

I added to my pom such dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${version.arquillian}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-alpha-1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When I run `mvn clean install` it compiles and run unit-tests until face Arquillian annotated, after that I see that Jboss was started:

```
 20:01:45,917 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.1.1.GA (AS 7.2.1.Final-redhat-10) started in 3205ms - Started 150 of 220 services (69 services are passive or on-demand)
```

And seems the process fall asleep. In `server.log` I see that nothing was deployed. After 50 minutes of waiting I get such exception:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2,993.683 sec <<< FAILURE! - in my_package.AccountTest
my_package.AccountTest  Time elapsed: 2,993.683 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Could not start container
        at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedDeployableContainer.startInternal(ManagedDeployableContainer.java:167)
        at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.start(CommonDeployableContainer.java:113)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:199)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:163)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:157)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:77)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:70)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachSuiteContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:221)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startSuiteContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:86)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:68)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:97)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Managed server was not started within [60] s
        at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedDeployableContainer.startInternal(ManagedDeployableContainer.java:163)
        at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.start(CommonDeployableContainer.java:113)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:199)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:163)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$8.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:157)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:255)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:77)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController$2.perform(ContainerLifecycleController.java:70)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.forEachSuiteContainer(ContainerLifecycleController.java:221)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerLifecycleController.startSuiteContainers(ContainerLifecycleController.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:86)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:68)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:97)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

I am new to `Arquillian` I could forget basic things, so any help will be appropriate!

Comment: Most likely you run that JBoss (even if it is started by arquillian) with Java 8. [This does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899497/jboss-seems-to-hang-on-startup-at-the-command-line), so you should use Java 7.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, thanks, will know. I  checked out, I use 1.7: `INFO: Starting container with: [/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java`

Comment: Well ... Thinking about it, it is not exactly the described behavior. Your JBoss gets started. The behavior when running with Java 8 hangs at "starting". So, you really have another issue. Unfortunately, I don't know ...

Comment: Try `org.jboss.as:jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed:7.1.3.Final` instead

Comment: I created project from archetype: `mvn archetype:generate \
 -DarchetypeGroupId=org.jboss.spec.archetypes \
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=jboss-javaee6-webapp-ear-archetype \
 -DarchetypeVersion=7.1.3.Final` and faced the same problem

Comment: And I see same story with WildFly 8.2 and 10.1. Have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that I had [non default management](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/JBoss+AS+7.0+-+Managed) port in `standalone.xml`

So adding this lines to `arquillian.xml` solved problem:

```
<property name="managementAddress">127.0.0.1</property>
<property name="managementPort">56999</property>
```